# Unresolved reference, in wrong test scope - Android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

Since I've updated to Android Studio 3.5, in my unit tests Android Studio shows unresolved reference for all the dependencies. The project compiles and the unit test runs successfully but Android Studio shows everything in red.

I've tried to clean, delete build and .gradle folder, invalidate caches but it doesn't work.

[image: Unresolved reference]

Comment: what is mockito version?

Comment: I am using version 2.24.5, but I do not think it is related to mockito because it happens in tests without it

Comment: Maybe not but give it a try for that.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only workaround to fix this until [issue 140375151](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140375151) is resolved is this:

1. Put the cursor on one of the affected references
2. Type `alt/options + Enter`
3. Choose `Inspection "Unresolved reference, in wrong test scope"`
4. Choose `Edit inspection profile setting`
5. Remove the check from the inspection setting to disable it and click `OK`

The unresolved references should no longer show as unresolved.

Answer (score 4):

This Google issue may be related. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140375151