# False unresolved reference in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just built my first App on Android studio. Everything was fine until few days while making some changes I got a notification for update and went on with it only for me to start getting `unresolved reference` error.

Even with that the application would build and run well but the problem is every other project I created after that follow suit with the same error.

I have followed tried several advice but to no avail.
I have deleted idea, imported the project from another one, done invalidate cache and restart, sync with system and sync with gradle.

I am currently trying to use Room on a new project and `synchronized` is marked `unresolved reference` as I tried to create singleton for my database.

I also noticed that my files are always corrupted, I have to go back to Git-hub to recopy those files even though they don't give error on compilation

In all I think these are the issues am facing both on current project and previous project
1. the `unresolved reference`

### Previous Project

```
        val sharedPref = activity!!.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val none = resources.getString(R.string.none)

        val countries = arrayListOf<String>("Nigeria", "Zambia", "Ethiopia", "Ghana", none)
        val greenWallCountries = arrayListOf<String>("Great green")

        Collections.sort(countries, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context!!, R.layout.spinner_item, countries)
        locationSpinner.adapter = adapter



        locationSpinner.isEnabled = false
        var chosen: String? = null
        greenwallVG.setOnClickListener {

            chosen = "ggw"
            greenwallVG.setBackgroundColor(R.color.primaryTransparent)
            countriesVG.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorNeutral)

            locationSpinner.isEnabled = false

            Toast.makeText(context!!, "$chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

### Current Project

**synchronized is marked unresolve reference here

```
package com.example.contactmvvm

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.internal.synchronized

@Database(entities = [ContactEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class ContactDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getContactDao():ContactDao

    companion object{
        private var instance:ContactDatabase?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            instance?: synchronized(this){
                instance?: Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                ContactDatabase::class.java, "contact_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()


            }

    }

}
```

2. error: Cannot find getter for field.
   private int id;

```
    package com.example.contactmvvm

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "contacts_table")
class ContactEntity(
    val firstName:String,
    val lastName:String,
    val sex: String,
    val address:String
    ) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private var id:Int = 0


}
```

Is there something else to be done to annul this error.

Comment: Maybe related to this error in Android Studio 4 Canary 6 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707769/unresolved-reference-in-wrong-test-scope-android-studio-3-5/59311273#59311273

Answer (score 0):

The [`synchronized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html) keyword had been deprecated in Kotlin.

While it clearly reads:

> `UnsupportedOperationException` - **always**

Therefore, even if it would be known, it would still be quite useless.

`kotlinx.coroutines.internal.synchronized` reads "internal" and obviously is something else. The best alternative might be `Coroutines.Sync.Mutex`, once `synchronized` won't exist anymore.

Comment: Does this mean I have to add coroutines to my dependencies?

Comment: @Darotudeen you've obviously already added them... while I rather think it should work without synchronization, because in Java it also works without doing so.

Comment: Here's a working [example](https://gist.github.com/TannerGabriel/f5594ad3b2c9f2586f2275be5103b29e#file-appdatabase-kt) (which uses the deprecated `synchronized` keyword)... but it might throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`. The question does not state which Kotlin versions you are using - and newer versions might complain - or not even know it anymore. Downgrading to some outdated Kotlin version should make it known, but is still a sub-optimal approach.